# join in Spark is too slow. Is there any way to optimize it?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

Here's my scenario. There are two data sources in HDFS. one is a list of elements with 20,000 lines, whereas the other is composed of 3,000,000,000 lines with the same element type. I intend to calculate the line count in dataset2 whose element exists in dataset1.

The code snippet is as follows:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("test")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val ds1Rdd = sc.textFile("/dataset_1").keyBy(line => line)
val ds2Rdd = sc.textFile("/dataset_2").keyBy(line => line)
println(ds1Rdd.join(ds2Rdd).count())
```

I could see that active stage is always stuck at `join` process from the Spark monitor webpage.

My execution parameters are `--master yarn-cluster --num-executors 32 --driver-memory 8g --executor-memory 4g --executor-cores 4`.

Is there anything that can be optimized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess Map-Side Join in Spark (http://dmtolpeko.com/2015/02/20/map-side-join-in-spark/) will resolve your problem. You could broadcast dataset1 and then do Map-Side Join.

Comment: Thanks, I've also found another related one (http://dongxicheng.org/framework-on-yarn/apache-spark-join-two-tables/), provided Chinese is accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You may able to send the small file to all the workers as a broadcast and then use filter.

What are the symptoms? Is it spilling in the shuffle? You can probably tune the memoryFractions, executor-cores, and the number/size of your partitions so that it doesn't spill.

Comment: I've found the `shuffle spill` item on spark monitor webpage. they are all displayed **0.0B** on all executors. I have to say, the progress stuck at `keyBy` for a very long time (several hours). And I try to replace `keyBy` with `map(line => (line, line))`, but it seems with no help.